# Add more column in existing table but it doesn't

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, artisan-migrate

```
$ php artisan migrate

In Connection.php line 647:

  SQLSTATE[42S01]: Base table or view already exists: 1050 Table 'users' alre
  ady exists (SQL: create table `users` (`id` int unsigned not null auto_incr
  ement primary key, `name` varchar(191) not null, `email` varchar(191) not n
  ull, `password` varchar(191) not null, `remember_token` varchar(100) null,
  `created_at` timestamp null, `updated_at` timestamp null) default character
   set utf8mb4 collate utf8mb4_unicode_ci)


In Connection.php line 449:

  SQLSTATE[42S01]: Base table or view already exists: 1050 Table 'users' alre
  ady exists
```

I am trying to add more column into users table but I can't. In terminal I write command php artisan migrate but Base table or view already exists: 1050 Table 'users' already exists. What can I do now?

Comment: do not use `Schema::create` use `Schema::table` to add more columns

Answer (score 0):

Use PHP artisan migrate:refresh
it will remove all table and create again all
or use Schema::table to add more columns

Comment: I also try it but  SQLSTATE[42S01]: Base table or view already exists: 1050 Table 'users' already exists.

Comment: go to database and delete all table manually

Comment: Thanks. It's working.

Comment: then up vote please

Answer (score 0):

You need to reference the table instead of calling the create method

```
Schema::table('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->string('email');
});
```

see [Laravel Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/migrations#creating-columns)